# AnyOf vs type array

Tags: jsonschema

Are there any differences between the following two JSON schemas validations or do they validate the same data structure?

```
SomeProperty
{
    "type": ["integer","string"]
}
```

```
SomeProperty
{
    "anyOf": [
         {
            "type": "integer"
         },
         {
             "type": "string"
         }
     ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are equivalent!

`type`

> The value of this keyword MUST be either a string or an array. If it
> is an array, elements of the array MUST be strings and MUST be unique.
>
> String values MUST be one of the six primitive types ("null",
> "boolean", "object", "array", "number", or "string"), or "integer"
> which matches any number with a zero fractional part.
>
> An instance validates if and only if the instance is in any of the
> sets listed for this keyword.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-01#section-6.1.1

Notice the last section "...in any of..."

Comment: If you have any specific questions which aren't on topic for StackOverflow, feel free to join the JSON Schema slack, found on the JSON Schema site.

Comment: You could use `oneOf` in place of `anyOf` in your example. While with this example they are they same, they do have different implications when you include other keywords.

Comment: For anyone else ending up here - they are equivalent in this case because the example is using simple types. In case your property can contain different **objects** with different properties each, we need to use `anyOf` to be able to specify the properties of each object individually.